# How can I find the total number of anchor tags in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I have one Action class in struts2. I supply one HTML file to the Action class.

How can I find the total number of `anchor` tags in an HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just after links:

```
alert(document.links.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, you do this:

```
var totalAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;
```